Можно ли установить LFS GitHub на windows 7
Хотел начать делать игру на юнити с использованием гитхаба но не смог скачать LFS скорей всего потомучто у меня виндовс 7

Напишите как Вы пытались устанавливать и какие ошибки получили, нужна конкретика. Скачивать не нужно, нужно именно устанавливать git lfs install
